# How to align Label of text area to top and right?

Tags: html

Here is my code:

```
.labelcss{
  width: 180px; 
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:right;
  vertical- align: text-top;
}

<label class="labelcss" for="address">Address: </label>
<textarea name="address" id="address">
```

My address label is positioned inferiorly. I need to position it to the top and right, Just like this:

[image]

Comment: give outer div `position:relative` and `.labelcss` `position:absolute` after that try to give  `.labelcss` `top:0` right:0` put the value that will help you in `top` and `right`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:top;`, not `vertical- align:text-top;`. This will make sure that your text is not aligned to the bottom, like it currently is.

```css
.labelcss{
  width: 180px; 
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:right;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<label class="labelcss" for="address">Address: </label>
<textarea name="address" id="address">
```